# A book on the basics of von Neumann-Bernays-Gödel set theory?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, self-learning, big-list

During this summer, I am taking an introductory course on "**von Neumann-Bernays-Gödel set theory**."
My professor is really good in this subject and he doesn't use any reference book except his notes. Since I have a hard time to understand some axioms, their need in this theory, and consequences of some of those axioms; I am looking for a good book for self-study.
Free online book or a PDF would be much better.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: See [von Neumann-Bernays-Gödel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory#References) for references: [Bernays](https://books.google.it/books?id=YVKVAwAAQBAJ), [Gödel](https://books.google.it/books?id=NVbQCwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), [Cohen](https://books.google.it/books?id=Q3VoJCRtQa4C&printsec=frontcover) are available. For a textbook see Mendelson.

Comment: Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA231), CRC Press (6th ed 2015), page 231.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Aha, that's what I get for trying to search a non-searchable pdf! Derp. You're quite right, it's been a long time since I looked at that book.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Why don't you add that as an answer?

Comment: Maybe you have trouble understanding it because it's a very dubious model of set theory. In my opinion, it might be possible to learn how to write a proof in NBG but that doesn't mean everything it can prove is actually true. I feel like it was created to satisfy some of the intuitive properties of Naive set theory and be a stronger consistent subtheory of Naive set theory than ZF. NBG appears to break the obviously true assumption that a proper class is something and each of them has a set that contains only that class and in fact refutes it. There may be a model of NBG in NF. That is, it

Comment: might be possible to find an intuitive injection from strings of characters that represent a statement in NBG to strings of characters that represent a statement in NF such that when one string can be decided from another 2 strings in NBG, its image can also be deduced from the image of the other 2 strings in NF.

Comment: @Timothy Is the implication being made that ZFC is a dubious model of set theory? Because NBG is a conservative extension of ZFC https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136215/difference-between-zfc-nbg and you mention ZF instead of ZFC so it's not clear to me either way.

Comment: @Timothy I also don't understand the relevance of your comment about NF. Is the mere fact that there *might* be an interpretation of NBG in NF supposed to make us skeptical about NBG? Or if that's not what you're saying, what are you saying?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a textbook dealing with [NBG set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory#References), see:

Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA231), CRC Press (6th ed 2015), page 231-on.

Answer (score 0):

[Сlassical Set Theory: Theory of Sets and Classes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/370221536_Slassical_Set_Theory_Theory_of_Sets_and_Classes) by Taras Banakh